# Find the parent of a process

Tags: shell-script, process

I am trying to write a script to help with computer security. I am trying to look for open ports, find the PID, and find what called it.

I have it working, where my output looks something like this:

```
IPV4 - 1234 - 2566/nc
Running from: `/bin/nc.openbsd`
Command run: `nc -l 1234`
```

Where I was able to get those values from `netstat`, `/proc/$PID/exe` and `/proc/$PID/cmdline`

However, in the nature of looking for backdoors, there may be a script on my computer somewhere, that would call `nc`. Is it possible, from the PID of `nc`, to find the original scripts location? I've tried looking at the other files in `/proc/$PID/*` to no avail.

Say in `/etc/rc.local` I put the line `nc -l 1234`, Could I get something that would tell me that the nc command was opened by `/etc/rc.local`?

Comment: Note that the parent of `nc` might be already dead. If it is, you won't be able to find anything about it unless you've been logging a lot more than what is normally logged. All of this won't find any backdoors except some extremely naive ones.

Comment: Also, even if the process that started the `nc` is still active - it could just do  a double fork before execing the nc - which is all it takes to get that nc adopted by a system process.

Answer (score 10):

To get the parent PID of the process, portably (POSIXly), you can use:

```
ps -p "$PID" -o ppid=
```

or (on Linux):

```
grep '^PPid' "/proc/$PID/status" |cut -f2
```

for more ways, see https://superuser.com/questions/150117/how-to-get-parent-pid-of-a-given-process-in-gnu-linux-from-command-line

Comment: That shows the parent PID, however lets pretend we have this scenario:

I have a script `./test.sh` that contains the following line: `nc -l 1234`. Now, in one terminal tab, I run the script: `$ ./test.sh`, and leave it running while I open a new tab. If I find the parent PID of `nc`, it will display `bash` rather than `/path/to/test.sh`.

I am looking on how I could get `/path/to/test.sh`.

Answer (score -1):

I ended up using the following:

`grep -r "$command" $(ls -l /proc/$pid/cwd | awk '{ print $11 }') | awk -F: '{ print $1 }'`

Where `$command="$(cat /proc/$pid/cmdline | sed 's\x0/ g' | sed 's/.$//')"`

Which will recursively grep through the files in the directory that the script is in to find the file containing the command line that ran the nc command.

Seems kind of messy, so if anyone could help clean that up a bit that'd be great :)

Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: That is very messy, insecure and unreliable indeed. `cwd` is the current working directory of the process, that has no reason to have anything to do with the path of the script. Files can have blanks and : in their names. Your first `sed` command doesn't make sense. `readlink -f` to get the target of a link.

Answer (score -1):

You can use get the pid running location using the below command

> ls -l /proc/PID_id/cwd

Comment: `/proc/$PID/cmdline` would probably be more use to OP.