# How to find a process's parent

Tags: linux, process

In `ps` one can see all the processes that running in my system.

How can I check for each process which process has started them?

For example if process A starts process B, how can I find by looking at process B, that process A is its parent?

Comment: Perhaps https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169728/117549 ?

Answer (score 2):

You can `ps --ppid <process_id> -o pid=`

Comment: Thank you, this is the cleanest option !! ... does it work at Linux and macOS?

Answer (score 1):

To find a process's parent using only `/proc`, look for `PPid` in the corresponding task's status:

```
grep PPid /proc/${pid}/task/${pid}/status
```

(replacing the two instances of `${pid}` with the child pid).

Answer (score 0):

Find the parent process for a given process:

`ps -cp <process_id> -o ppid=""`

Comment: I don't have those flags in my ps. How can I find that information by looking at `/proc/pid`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `pstree` to view the whole tree of processes.
If you want to use `/proc` the file `/proc/<PID>/task/<PID>/status` contains information about the process. The entry `PPid` is what you are looking for - the parent process id.