# How to find out why postgres was started by systemd and prevent it?

Tags: debian, systemd, postgresql, autostart

I already checked the /proc/PID directory.
I'd like to prevent any services like postgres from starting except if I start them myself.
Hence, I'd like to find out why postgres was started. I saw that it was running with `sudo lsof -i` even though it wasn't running before and I haven't started it directly.

I'm running Debian10 and two days ago there were some updates for postgres which I installed. I checked for processes running with lsof -i on the same day but Apper's history doesn't show me datetimes (neither does the bash history) so it could have been before the update and hence postgres might have autostarted after the update. If it does autostart after updating I'd like to know how to prevent this but that would probably be a separate question.

There are multiple postgres processes. Each have just another postgres process as parent. Its parent PID is 1 which is systemd. When running `rkhunter -c` it warns about a suspicious file type at: `/dev/shm/PostgreSQL.{long-number}`

Answer (score 2):

To find out why postgres was started, I would trace the [parent process](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169728/117549) upwards. Since you found that yours ended in PID 1, which is systemd on your system, I would then ask systemd to tell me about the status of its units, then look for that process. You could grep for the process name:

```
$ systemctl status | grep -B3 'postgres'
```

If three lines aren't enough to uncover the unit that's responsible, increase it until it does.

If you have the PID handy,

```
$ systemctl status 1024  ## example PID
```

then this command will ask systemd to tell you the status (and thus the name) of the unit that the process belongs to.

Once you have the systemd unit's name, you can prevent it from starting by running:

```
# systemctl mask --now unit-name-here
```

... the `--now` option also stops the unit immediately.

Comment: That's helpful but it only tells that it was started by system-postgresql.slice->postgresql@11-main.service and not why it was started.

Comment: Systemd starts the unit it it's been configured to start. If you didn't expect it, you might have to consider the malware possibility. Perhaps some other (intended) service depends on it?

Comment: The possibility of malware, albeit theoretically unlikely, and the possibility of another (intended) service depending on it are why I'd like to know how to find out what (how) it was started.

Comment: I'm not able to test at the moment, but `systemctl list-dependencies --reverse postgresql@11-main` may tell you if there are units that brought in postgres as a dependency.

Comment: When you do test, take a gander at `/usr/share/doc/postgresql-common/README.systemd` and https://sources.debian.org/src/postgresql-common/215/debian/maintscripts-functions/#L79

Comment: @mYnDstrEAm I'm not sure how far to rewind the clock, here. Presumably systemd started postgres because it was told to, either directly or via dependency.

Comment: So out of nowhere I got a black screen which is why force shutdown the machine. After rebooting I got the error Xsession: warning unable to write to /tmp: X session may exit with an error. I could open the console with ctrl+alt+f1 and am currently on the other machine (which apparently was shut down...and I got some new errors right after booting in addition to the usual ones) trying to figure out how to start the xsession / KDE. `startx` gives unable to write authority file /tmp/serverauth.id. Probably it's because the root partition is out of space again. That was happening frequently...

Comment: before but recently I moved some files to clear space and just checked that over 300 MB of free space are available hours before it happened. This might be totally unrelated. On the other machine I don't have the postgres updates installed. Postgres started automatically after boot (almost the single thing showing up in lsof -i and I'm relatively sure I disabled it. Anyways, I'll try to get it working again, will disable postgres again and will create a new question and/or bug report for a) how to disable such services permanently and b) including (better) info on service-starts in Debian.

Comment: It's because I don't have any disk space available. Currently trying to look for something to safely delete because I don't want to delete any logs (large log files are usually the main cause of the disk space running out). The 300 MB are available again after clearing var/cache/apt. I only updated a few probably small packages today. Maybe I'll check how much space they take up. I didn't get any running out of disk space message.

Comment: Just to chime in I discovered exactly the same problem after updating from ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04.